# Select column names by regex pattern

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I want to select all columns that start in one of the four following ways: CB, LB, LW, CW but not any columns that have the string "con."

My current approach is:

```
tester <- df_ans[,names(df_ans) %in% colnames(df_ans)[grepl("^(LW|LB|CW|CB)[A-Z_0-9]*",colnames(df_ans))]]
tester <- tester[,names(tester) %in% colnames(tester)[!grepl("con",colnames(tester))]]
```

Is there a better / more efficient way to do this in a library like dplyr?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `matches`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select(matches("^(CB|LB|LW|CW)"), -matches("con"))
#   CB1 LB2 CW3 LW20
#1   3   9   6    1
#2   3   3   4    5
#3   7   7   7    7
#4   5   8   7    2
#5   6   3   3    3
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 10 * 5, replace = TRUE),
       ncol = 10, dimnames = list(NULL, c("CB1", "LB2", "CW3", "WC1",
     "LW20", "conifer", "hercon", "other", "other2", "other3"))))
```

Comment: Ah, did not know about matches.  Thank you!

Comment: I am getting "Error: All arguments must be character vectors, not integer"

Comment: @Parseltongue  Sorry, I have to remove the `one_of`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
nms <- names(df_ans)
df_ans[ grepl("^(LW|LB|CW|CB)", nms) & !grepl("con", nms) ]
```